# Conflict Preventing Background Video from Showing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

On my site http://tsawebmaster1.hhstsa.com/drones/index.html, I have a background video that is supposed to show using the bigvideo.js plugin. For some reason it is not showing. How can this be solved?

I believe this has something to do with multiple jquery files overriding each other. Is this possible and the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open up your console. You can see the following error:

```
document.getElementByTagName is not a function
```

You are missing an 's'

the correct method is:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName(name);
```

**Pic**

[image: console]

Comment: you need to open up the developer console to see it, it says its in navigation.js line 89. Note, that the line number might not be correct, but its close. Edit: added picture

Comment: should this var myVideo = document.getElementById("video1");  be "Elements" as well

Comment: check these out for all the correct methods: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document
http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_document.asp
good luck!!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use Jquery No Conflict as follow:

```
<script src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script>
$.noConflict();
// Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

Comment: is that the issue that I am having on my website?

Comment: I don't know if this will fix the issue in your website :S, but why you don't use background video by styling, not a unique library for this !!

Comment: this is incorrect, if it doesnt solve the problem why post it?